# Horizontal line to join married couple in genealogy trees

Tags: genealogytree, genealogy

I am working on a genealogy tree using tikz and I am looking for some package to simplify and automate at least some of the construction. I am aware of the genealogytree package, but it apparently lacks one feature that I would like to have: I want to join a married couple with a horizontal line, as in the picture:

[image: Genealogy tree sample]

Is there a way to do this with genealogytree package, and if not, is there some other efficient way to make a genealogy tree?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it is feasible with genealogytree. The closest I come is like this, where I remove the normal edges from parents, and add a new edge between them, extra high. But I need one child to be a pivot below the center, and draw the extra edge only to it, because otherwise the two sets of edges won't fit together.

(When I started using genealogytree I experimented because I also wanted trees to look like in your example, but soon I came to appreciate having the edges below the parents so there is room for more than two spouses.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}

\begin{document}

\begin{genealogypicture}[
  template=signpost,
  parent distance=1cm,
  options for family={fam1}{extra edges={man,wife}{c2}{yshift=12mm}},
  ]
  child[id=fam1]{
    p[disconnect,id=man]{Husband}
    g[disconnect,id=wife]{Wife}
    c{Child1} c[id=c2,pivot]{Child2} c{Child3} c{Child4}
  }
\end{genealogypicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is quite useful actually. I also became aware of the problem with more than two spouses, but it is rare enough that I plan to treat it as a special case to be adjusted manually somehow.